# Getting OS memory size from java

Tags: java, memory, operating-system

Are there any way to get the size of the total memory on the operating system from java? Using

```
Runtime.getRuntime().maxMemory()
```

returns the allowed memory for the JVM, not of the operating system. Does anyone have a way to obtain this (from java code)?

Comment: What is it you need to _know_?

Comment: @Thorbjørn: If I'm running on a machine with 2GB RAM but the JVM is limited to 1GB, I want to obtain the 2GB size and not the 1GB size returned from the sample code. Or are you asking why I need it?

Comment: I am asking what you need it _for_?

Comment: As part of a library that is to collect some usage statistics (with user consent, of course)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

```
com.sun.management.OperatingSystemMXBean bean =
  (com.sun.management.OperatingSystemMXBean)
    java.lang.management.ManagementFactory.getOperatingSystemMXBean();
long max = bean.getTotalPhysicalMemorySize();
```

returns available RAM size for JVM (limited by 32bit), not the heap size.

Comment: "Access restriction: The type 'OperatingSystemMXBean' is not API" in Java 8, referring specifically to the one in `com.sun.management`.

Answer (score 3):

There is no Java-only way to get that information. You may use `Runtime.exec()` to start OS-specific commands, e.g. `/usr/bin/free` on Linux. Still on Linux systems, you can use Java file access classes (`FileInputStream`) to parse `/proc/meminfo`.

Answer (score 3):

that is not possible with pure Java, your program runs on java virtual machine, and therefore it is isolated from OS.  I suggest 2 solutions for this:

1) You can use a JNI and call a C++ function to do that
2) Another option is to use `Runtime.exec()`. Then you have to get the info from `"cat /proc/meminfo"`

Answer (score 0):

You can get the RAM usage with this. This is the same value that taskmanager in windows shows

```
    com.sun.management.OperatingSystemMXBean bean = (com.sun.management.OperatingSystemMXBean)java.lang.management.ManagementFactory.getOperatingSystemMXBean();
    double percentage = ((double)bean.getFreeMemorySize() / (double)bean.getTotalPhysicalMemorySize()) * 100;
    percentage = 100 - percentage;
    System.out.println("RAM Usage: " + percentage + "%");
```