# Total RAM in Java

Tags: java, jvm

I have a piece of code that caclulates the total RAM in my system [not Java VM Heap Size].

It is as follows:

```
        OperatingSystemMXBean operatingSystemMXBean = 
            ManagementFactory.getOperatingSystemMXBean();

        Method m = operatingSystemMXBean.getClass().
                    getDeclaredMethod("getTotalPhysicalMemorySize");

        m.setAccessible(true);

        Object value = m.invoke(operatingSystemMXBean);

        if (value != null)
        {
            System.out.println(value);
        }
```

The problem with the above piece of code is that it gives me incorrect values sometimes. For example in a system with 8 GB of RAM, using a 32 bit JVM, it shows 4 GB. I guess it is because the JVM is 32 bit and using 32 bits 4 GB is the maximum that it can address.

Can anyone suggest ways/workarounds for this. Basically how do we get the total RAM in a system using a 32 bit JVM.

Full details of my System are as follows:

OS : Windows 7 
CPU : Intel i7 
JDK : Sun Java 1.6 Update 21, 32 bit 
RAM : 8 GB

Comment: Not sure if this helps, but it has some info: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25552/using-java-to-get-os-level-system-information

Comment: Here is exactly the same question with some answers: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4335356/getting-os-memory-size-from-java

Answer (score 2):

Cannot think of a pure Java way, but you can use Runtime.exec() to run the following command

```
wmic MEMPHYSICAL Get MaxCapacity
```

EDIT:
Correction - the above gives the maximum capacity for installing RAM. Try the OS alias like below:

```
wmic OS Get TotalVisibleMemorySize
```