# Java program result does not match with command terminal results

Tags: java

I want to get

- free disk space
- total disk space
- total RAM
- free RAM

using Java code. (**df -h**)

I have done several codes, but it does not match with the command terminal results.

1)

```
FileSystemView fsv = FileSystemView.getFileSystemView();

File[] drives = File.listRoots();
if (drives != null && drives.length > 0) {
    for (File aDrive : drives) {
        System.out.println("\tFree space: " + aDrive.getFreeSpace());
    }
}
```

2)

```
File file = new File("/");
double freeSize = file.getFreeSpace();
```

3)
Also I use:

```
long freeMemory=Runtime.getRuntime().freeMemory();
long totalMemory = Runtime.getRuntime().totalMemory();
long maxMemory = Runtime.getRuntime().maxMemory();

Command terminal results:-
root@sumi:~# free -m
          total        used        free      shared  buff/cache available
Mem:       7896        5516        1121         279        1258      2110
Swap:      8108          36        8072
```

Java program results

```
totalmemory = 1029.177344;
maxmemory = 1908.932608;
freememory = 1013.071192;
```

Please, help me to get the system's free disk space, total disk space, total RAM, and free RAM results to be same as the command terminal results using a Java program.

Comment: What is the result that you are getting and how does it differ from your expected result?

Comment: 407G is the available memory shown in command terminal . but java program return 429.7GB. I need java code to get  system's  free disk space,total disk space,total RAM and free RAM.

Comment: just to be sure, if you say `407G` do you mean `407GiB` or `407GB`? if so, you just need to convert your `429.7GB` to `GiB`.

Comment: Java is not designed to provide *system specific* information. Especiall your approach to abuse the fact that in unix "everything is a file" has no guarantee of success. You migt better call `df` using the [ProcessBuilder](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/ProcessBuilder.html) and read its output: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3643939/java-process-with-input-output-stream

Comment: Using `file.getFreeSpace` works for me, but I would probably have to agree with Timothy Truckle, that reading `df` output would be the better choice. Otherwise you could try using `file.getUsableSpace();` instead of `file.getFreeSpace();`, since it will deliver a more accurate result.

Comment: @AngryRedPanda i mean 407GB

Comment: It should work in all operating system. I checked with file.getUsableSpace();It also doesnot give accurate results. Program results 1013.071192 MB and command terminal results      1121MB.

Comment: I think this might be a MB versus MiB issue.

Comment: java.lang.Runtime provides information about JVM not OS. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4335356/getting-os-memory-size-from-java